# Ethics of Spinoza - forte ea de causa

Tags: translation-explanation, spinoza, ethica

Spinoza, Ethics, De Deo, Propositio 28, Scholium:

> Sequitur quod Deus non potest proprie dici causa esse remota rerum
> singularium nisi **forte ea de causa** ut scilicet  has ab iis quas
> immediate produxit vel potius quae ex absoluta ejus natura sequuntur,
> distinguamus

I can't understand meaning of **ea** in **forte ea de causa** and I don't know how **forte** here can mean **by chance**.

Shirle translates it:

> perchance for the purpose

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *ea* (= *eā*) modifies *causa*, using the very common adjective–preposition–object of preposition arrangement: 'for this reason.'

The *forte* is from the noun *fors*, 'chance' (not the adjective *fortis*, 'strong, brave'); so the ablative/adverbial form means 'by chance.'

Comment: Thank you. The Latin word order is confusing for me. How can I learn it?

Comment: Note that *forte* does not really mean “by chance” here. *Nisi forte/vero* (+ indicative) is a standing expression indicating an exception which the author may grant but thinks is improbable or does at least not detract from his original claim. It can be translated as “unless perhaps” or “unless I suppose” or “unless of course” etc. Famous Cicero quote: *Nemo enim fere saltat sobrius, nisi forte insanit.* – For almost nobody dances sober, unless perhaps he is insane.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel. I grant that it may be a weakened idea of 'chance'; but it would still be very common to use 'by chance' (or 'perchance') in English in such cases, where it's more like a simple 'perhaps.' (In fact, the 'hap' of 'perhaps' also means 'luck' or 'chance' so that, etymologically speaking, 'perhaps' also means 'by chance.')

Comment: @cnread I suppose it is quite close, I just wanted to point out that *nisi forte* is a common collocation and one need not interpret it as the autor talking about any actual “chance.”